# get data from firestore document reference from angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have below code which getting data from the firestore directly from angular.
as you can look  console.log(data.city); where I have document reference of city.
so how could I access data from document reference in angular?

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCR8p.png)

Answer (score 3):

Document references in Firestore won't give you data right away. You'll have to use that document reference and get data from firebase.

It is just like getting data manually referencing a document.
For instance,

```
this.afs.collection('users').doc('doc_id').get().then(result => console.log(result.data()));;//if you want to access a specific document
```

if you already have a reference (like city in your case),

```
data.city.get().then(result => console.log(result.data()));
```

You can use :any datatype to data object if it throws any invalid reference exception

Hope this helps!!